# Preferred file organization for subviews

Tags: ios

Suppose I have a UIViewController in which the view has two subviews, UIScrollView and a UIView. Should I write the functionalities for both subviews inside the UIViewController .m file, or is it recommended to put the subview functionality inside its own .h/.m files?

If it is better to keep them in the same parent view file, what happens if I have a lot more subviews? What is the best practice for this?

Comment: don't make things complicated by putting everything in a single viewController, its better to keep them in separate classes.

Comment: it doesn't matter whether you have lots of subViews or less, if they are just views with no functionality in it then you can just put the code in same controller but if it has added functionality with it then better you create separate class for that...it will simplify the things also the code will be more readable and easy to debug n maintain...